import tempfile ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tempfile'
When I'm installing any module using
pip install "<module>"

it is showing the error

import tempfile
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tempfile'

Can someone tell me how to install this module as it says no module named tempfile present when installing any other module.

What is your Python and pip versions?

Do you need to reinstall Python? Because I can also find the corresponding official documentation in version 2.5 of Python.https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/tempfile.html

You have tagged python-3.x so I assume that's what you're using. The tempfile module is standard in python 3.x.x therefore I deduce that your Python environment is corrupt

@GinoMempin python version is 3.11.3 and as for the pip it showing the the same error so, i guess problem is in pip
